# Where does `recipe` hash come from in chef?

Tags: php, chef-infra

To use `php-fpm` I use this code.

```
$ knife cookbook create ppa
$ vi site-cookbooks/ppa/recipes/default.rb

apt_repository "nginx-php" do
  uri "http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/php5/ubuntu"
  distribution node['lsb']['codename']
  components ["main"]
  keyserver "keyserver.ubuntu.com"
  key "C300EE8C"
end
```

http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apt

And added `recipe[apt]` to `runlist`.

I want to know where come from this `recipe` hash.
Does `keys` are always same as directories of `cookbooks`?

I even don't know when these directories are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is as follows

```
recipe[cookbook_name::recipe_name]
```

A short hand for `recipe[cookbook_name::default]` is

```
recipe[cookbook_name]
```

The `cookbook_name` name is defined in each cookbook's `metadata.rb` file. You cannot assume that the directory name will be the same as the cookbook name.

The `recipe_name` is the the name of a file in the recipes directory sans the `.rb` extension.